# INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton's text is truncated

Tags: ios, uikit, sirishortcuts

I am adding a `INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton` in a stack view and its text appears truncated:

[image: Added t...]

I am not setting any constraint on it, and the width comes from its own intrinsic content size:

[image: self.width = 136.6667 (content size) Intrinsic Content Size Constraint]

Is it an iOS 13 bug?

Answer (score 1):

**INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton** seems to miss it's size calculations by a bit
add width constraint to your **INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton** to be just a bit bigger then **intrinsicContentSize.width**

```
let button = INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton(style: .whiteOutline)
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: button.intrinsicContentSize.width + 16).isActive = true
```

you'll still get your intent phrase cut, but at least "Added to Siri" will be fully shown making this less disturbing

Comment: I hoped for a less hacky solution :(

Comment: tell me about it =(